# Odoo can't reach localhost: The connection was reset

Tags: installation, localhost, odoo, odoo-13

I just installed odoo 13 community but I can't reach the server.

I have followed step by step this website to install it: https://www.candidroot.com/blog/our-candidroot-blog-1/post/how-to-install-odoo-13-in-ubuntu-18-04-14

The difference is I installed odoo from a .deb file and not from Git.

But when I start server with sudo systemctl start odoo, it works.

And when I start server with python3 /usr/bin/odoo -c /etc/odoo/odoo.conf, Firefox display "The connection was reset" and nothing is happening in the debug lines of terminal.

[image]

Here is my conf file:

[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Thank you,

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I start server with sudo systemctl start odoo, it works.

so it seems the port 8069 is not available anymore ...

To lookup the process using port 8069,
you can:
lsof -i|grep 8069
this will show the PID of that process, which you can kill:
sudo kill -9 PID
Make sure you stopped the daemon before

Comment: Thanks for reply. How am I supposed to do?